# Russian cartoon about bogatyr

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

This is a Russian cartoon about one of the Bogatyrs. Here are some elements I remember from it:

There is a talking horse who gambles with a talking tree for "Two half-kingdoms", with the bet being his hide if he loses. He loses, and the other characters end up bailing him out somehow.

In another scene, some of the characters meet a charlatan offering them "free" elephant rides. When they try to get off the elephant, the charlatan says that "The ride is free. You have to pay to get off the elephant". One of the characters sends the elephant into a rage to get away from the charlatan.

There is a three-headed dragon. The main characters and the dragon buy a "Miracle horse" (Actually a camel) from yet another charlatan. The charlatan tells them that the "miracle horse" pretty much doesn't need to eat. Both characters find out the hard way that, while they don't have to feed it much, it drinks A LOT.

There's a scene with Salovey the Robber.

Answer (score 1):

See "Ilya Muromets i Solovey Razboynik" (which can be translated as Ilya from Murom-city and Nightingale the Bandir). IMDB reference: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1189893/

It is one of four or more cartoons about Russian bogatyrs (folk warriors) - Ilya, Dobrynya and Alyosha. Other cartoons in the series are "Tri bogatyrya i Shamakhanskaya tsaritsa" (Three bogatyrs and Shamakhan princess), "Dobrynya Nikitich i Zmey Gorynych" (Dobrynya and the Dragon), "Alyosha Popovich i Tugarin Zmey" (Alyosha and Tugarin-the-snake) - there may be more, I stopped following the series when kids grew up ;)